# How do I merge multiple json objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

I use different urls get similar json data.

So that I can get more information in the same model

It has trouble me for a long time

i tried to use json.net for a single list.

```
string url1= "https://apt.data2.com";
string url2= "https://apt.data1.com";
var json1= webClient.DownloadString(url1);
var json2= webClient.DownloadString(url2);
```

**These calls return multiple json objects with the same structure**

```
    {
        data: [
             {
               created_time: "1457332172",
              text: "什麼東西",
              from: {
              username: "d86241",
              profile_picture: "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11371189_421316874725117_327631552_a.jpg",
              id: "397355082",
              full_name: "Jhao-wei Hvang"
    },
    id: "1200511729352353899"
      }
   ]
}
```

and

```
{
        data: [
             {
               created_time: "1111",
              text: "hi",
              from: {
              username: "22",
              profile_picture: "",
              id: "ss",
              full_name: "Hvang"
    },
    id: "1200511352353899"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to combine these objects to produce

```
  {
    data:[
    {
      created_time:"1234"
      text:...
       ....
        ......
        },
    id:1234....
      ]

    data:[
    {
      created_time:"4567"
      text:....
       ....
        ......
        },
    id:4567....
      ]
    }
```

How do I merge these into a single json object?

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
     {
@ Item.text
    }
```

Comment: Refer the SO [how-do-i-combine-two-arrays-from-two-jobjects-in-newtonsoft-json-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12516510/how-do-i-combine-two-arrays-from-two-jobjects-in-newtonsoft-json-net)

Comment: @WhoAmI Thank you for your valuable time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two Json.NET arrays by concatenating contained elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14121010/merge-two-json-net-arrays-by-concatenating-contained-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var jObject1 = // Your first json object as JObject
var jObject2 = // Your second json object as JObject 
jObject1.Merge(jObject2);
```

Comment: This needs a better explanation. It is not clear what a [JObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) is or how to make one